# Spring Data Redis: Setting a Password

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-redis

I have a need to provide a secure connection to Redis from my microservices.

So if I want to add the ability to support authentication so that a client can send an AUTH command with a password.  See http://redis.io/topics/security

How can I do this with the Spring Data Redis implementation?

Answer (score 10):

Just set the `password` on [LettuceConnectionFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceConnectionFactory.html#setPassword-java.lang.String-) or [JedisConnectionFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.html#setPassword-java.lang.String-), depending on which driver you're using. If you use Spring Boot, set `spring.data.redis.password=…` in your application configuration (see [Common application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

If you have access to configuration file of redis you can find the password by searching : `requirepass`

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of `Jedis` client, setting the password to the `JedisConnectionFactory` is deprecated. Therefore you should set the `Redis` authentication password to the `RedisStandaloneConfiguration`, `RedisSentinelConfiguration` or `RedisClusterConfiguration`.